# Make Link Inside A container With slideToggle() work

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have this markup:

```
<ul><li id="link-notifications">
  <ul class="list-notifications" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="/link/to">Item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

with this Jquery:

```
$('#link-notifications').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();           
   $(this).find('.list-notifications').slideToggle('medium');       
});
```

but whenever the list slides down, and I click the link, the list just slides back up. I have heard that stopPropagation works so I added it but it does not work. I even tried adding it to the slideToggle callback but it just stops the slideUp action. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding `click` event only to `#link-notifications` ans escaping its inner contents.

```
$('#link-notifications, :not("#link-notifications > *")').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();           
   $(this).find('.list-notifications').slideToggle('medium');       
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9dCeD/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  `e.stopPropagation()` inside that event but in the click of the link.

Just add

```
$('.list-notifications').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6pYU/1/

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="link-notifications">
    <a href="#">link-notifications</a>
        <ul class="list-notifications">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

jQuery

```
$('#link-notifications>a').click(function(event){
   $(this).siblings('ul.list-notifications').slideToggle('medium');      
});​
```

I attached the event not to a parent of what I wanted to slide but a sibling. This keeps weird events from bubbling.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/59e3F/